# How can I make Netbeans 6.7 recognize JSF tags in facelets?

Tags: java, ide, jsf, netbeans, facelets

I would like to upgrade from Netbeans 6.5 to Netbeans 6.7.  However, I've encountered an annoyance.  Netbeans 6.5 recognizes jsf tags, but Netbeans 6.7 does not.  Here are the screenshots:

[image: Netbeans 6.7.1 screenshot]

[image: Netbeans 6.5 screenshot]

**Why isn't Netbeans 6.7.1 not recognizing and matching JSF tags?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools --> Options --> Miscellaneous --> Files . Then choose the File extension 'xhtml' and choose to associate it with file type (MIME) text/x-facelet-x-jsp

That should do it for you =)

Comment: I actually chose "JSF Configuration Files (text/x-jsf+xml)."  It's working like a champ.  Thanks!